# Unable to run jar file

Tags: java, jar

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Created-By: 1.7.0_01 (Oracle Corporation)  
Main-Class: useDisplay
```

NOTE: There is a blank line after the Main-Class

**display.java**

```
public class display  
{  
    public void displayText()
    {
       System.out.println ("In displayText");
    }
}
```

**useDisplay.java**

```
public class useDisplay  
{
   public static void main (String args[])  
   {
      System.out.println ("In displayText");
   }
}
```

I ran the following commands:

```
javac *java
jar cf my1.jar MANIFEST.MF *class  
java -jar my1.jar
```

I got the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(LauncherHelper.java:399) 

at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:463)
```

This should be a very simple example.  The program works without the jar file.   I have no idea what it's complaining about.

Comment: do you have a source package?

Comment: what does javac *class do? Is that something new in Java 7? Is that a new way to compile all the java source files in a directory? I assume that's not the same as using javac display.java and javac useDisplay.java

Comment: Sorry, typo java *java.  I fixed the description already.

Comment: Cool... I thought maybe I was missing something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to add a -m to the jar command to use the MANIFEST.MF file you are specifying

```
jar cfm my1.jar MANIFEST.MF *class
```

Comment: Oh yes, that is it.  I knew it was something simple.  Thank you.